# Is it a bad idea to store html in a DB so that users can edit it?

Tags: php, mysql

I just wanted to get your opinions on how I plan to handle a situation.

Situation: I am developing a school's website where strict Board of Education policies will not allow anyone BUT me FTP access to the site. However, the school will have a group of six students in a "webpage" class to manage 10-12 pages that need frequent updating.

The pages all look pretty identical: header, navigation, side navigation (for that specific section (sports, academics, etc)), and the **main content**.

The main content is served by the div "content", so what I'm thinking to do is just to load all of #content's content from a Mysql db that is edited with another file (I pretty promise to use prepared statements).

Do you have any opinions on this, or maybe a better method? Thank you!

Comment: You're looking for a CMS, which does exactly that.

Comment: It is ok. And I'm glad you pretty promise to use prepared statements!

Comment: I feel like integrating a CMS would be more hassle than simply writing a quick function to edit pages with db pulls, tinymce formatting, and db updates. How would you suggest storing the html? longtext?

Comment: There is a lot more than just prepared statements to contend with. You will need to make sure that you escape/encode your output, strip tags that you don't want the user to add such as <script> or change the input to another format such as BB edit or preferably markdown. http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/

Comment: I think my situation is a little unique in the fact that on top of actually functioning, the site is part of a class where HTML use is encouraged / taught, so I think keeping the HTML markup is a good learning experience for those editing. However, I **totally** agree about stripping <script> and maybe a few other tags. Thanks for that tip! +1

Comment: Stripping tags won't secure it. Use a sane CMS or use a microformat that doesn't allow embedding arbitrary HTML. (I say this from experience, as trying to migrate away from HTML-in-the-database is a nightmare.)

Comment: @ankurkdotcom you dont have to strip anything if you use tinymce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you kepp your markup in a database, in order to get that one you need:

1. Parse config file(if any) and establish a connection
2. Do query and fetch the data
3. Append the results

When you keep your markup in a file, all you need to do is include that markup via `require()` language construct

**EDIT**

**To be very specific** - No. it's not a bad idea to store dynamic HTML content in a table. This is a **common practise**. But if you also store static content like header, navigation in a table for each page, it merely leads to **data duplication**.

I personaly would store the parts I never change in a file. The parts that tend to be "dynamic" I'd store in a table. I would add/edit them via TinyMCE using jquery-ajax.

An example of how I do that:

File: page_view.php

```
<?php

class Page_View // <- This isn't MVC
{
    private $data = array();

    public function render()
    {
        include('page_template.phtml');
        exit();
    }

    private function getTitle()
    {
       return $this->data['title'];
    }

    private function getBody()
    {
        return $this->data['body'];
    }

    private function getStaticBlock($file)
    {
        include($file);
    }

    public function setBody($body)
    {
       $this->data['body'] = $body;
    }

    public function setTitle($title)
    {
       $this->data['title'] = $title;
    }
}
```

File: page_template.phtml
?>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $this->getTitle(); ?></title>

<?php $this->getStaticBlock('/templates/blocks/header.phtml'); ?> 

<body>
 <div id="navigation">
  <?php $this->getStaticBlock('/templates/blocks/navigation.phtml'); ?>
 </div>

   <div id="content"><?php echo $this->getBody(); ?></div>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Example of usage:

```
<?php


// $data is what you got from a table


$page = new Page_View();
$page->setTitle($data['title']);
$page->setBody($data['body']);

$page->render();
```

Comment: Sorry for missing your point (possibly), are you suggesting storing the markup in a file and modifying that file with say.. PHP's file system functions?

Comment: Only for static pages. For dynamic content you need to store that in a database and do edit that content via some WYSIWYG editor, like TinyMCE

Comment: not really valid answer, youre just concluding that its easier to save data to a file based on the amount of code processing, not the data(amount) processing, db is safer and faster, and better to handle than any file.

Comment: @Ark this is not true. DB isn't option for static pages

Comment: There isnt such thing as "static page" its static just for the visitors, sooner or later youre gonna need change a thing there, on db you just login , easily find it by select or order, and change it.

Comment: 1) He said he has static parts: `header, navigation, side navigation`. He needs only to change the dynamic part like `body` or content of the page. 2) It's static for visitors - TRUE, but not for developer

Comment: Database suits best for dynamic content only.

Comment: @metal_fan its funny how YOU started the "static talk" and on your answer you just suggest its better via file even considering his question is about a dynamic content, but nevermind, its your opinion.

Comment: So what I am getting here is.. I won't be breaking any convention / be partaking in bad coding practice to store that particular html markup in the db, cool!

Comment: Thank you mainly for the effort you put in answering the question, and the examples you showed!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, storing arbitrary HTML in a database is a **nightmare** to maintain and secure. I'd look more closely at what you are trying to accomplish before engineering a new solution.

I'd strongly recommend a content management system. They're equipped to deal with this sort of work and there's no sense in rebuilding one from scratch.

If the selected students are going to be frequently updating the website, consider separating out that part of the site.

For example, if the main website is static but the frequently updated parts are a blog, set up a static site and either a subdomain or a sub-directory with a wordpress blog in it.

If the students are going to be editing the actual content of the page, a CMS like Drupal is far more effective for the task.